# Angular 2 - Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'my-datatable'

Tags: angular

I wanted to use guards and advance routing, so I followed the official routing tutorial

I created a module to put everything that concerned my component , inside
( customers.routing.ts, customers.service.ts, customers.component.ts ....)

since it returns that error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'settings' since it isn't a known property of 'my-datatable'.
1. If 'my-datatable' is an Angular component and it has 'settings' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-datatable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("v *ngIf="customers">
        <div class="customersDataTableWrapperDiv">
            <my-datatable [ERROR ->][settings]="tableSettings" (onError)="onDataTableError($event)" ></my-datatable>
        </div>
   "): ng:///CustomersModule/CustomersComponent.html@11:26
'my-datatable' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-datatable' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'my-datatable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    <div *ngIf="customers">
        <div class="customersDataTableWrapperDiv">
            [ERROR ->]<my-datatable [settings]="tableSettings" (onError)="onDataTableError($event)" ></my-datatable>
     "): ng:///CustomersModule/CustomersComponent.html@11:12 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
```

customers.component.html:

```
<my-datatable [settings]="tableSettings"></my-datatable>
```

datatable.component.ts:

```
...
@Component({
    selector: 'my-datatable',
    templateUrl: './dataTable.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dataTable.component.css'],
})

export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {
...
    @Input() settings: any;
```

but app.module.ts already uses that DataTableComponent, I did not remove it

here is my created module (which is now referred in app.module.ts for imports):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

import { CustomersComponent } from './customers.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';
import { CustomersService } from './customers.service';
import { CustomersRoutingModule } from './customers.routing';

import { DataTableModule } from '../components/dataTable/dataTable.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        CustomersRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        DataTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        CustomersComponent,
        CustomerComponent,
    ],
    providers: [CustomersService,FormBuilder],
})
export class CustomersModule {}
```

What could I have missed here?
thanks

edit: here is my DataTableModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableComponent } from './dataTable.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule,FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
    declarations: [DataTableComponent],
    exports: [DataTableComponent]
})
export class DataTableModule{
}
```

Comment: 'app.module.ts already uses that DataTableComponent'
Faced same kinda scenario. Waiting for an answer with the reason for the cause of error.

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk I updated my answer, give it a look. Also check my comments. Hope it helps! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoudl add your `DatatableComponent` to the module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    declarations: [DatatableComponent],
    exports: [DatatableComponent]
})
export class DatatableModule{
}
```

And in your view, import the module: `DatatableModule`.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [DatatableModule],
    declarations: [],
    exports: []
})
export class MyCurrentViewModule{
}
```

**Update 1:**

Try adding `CommonModule` to your `DatatableModule`, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DatatableComponent } from './datatable.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [DatatableComponent],
    exports: [DatatableComponent]
})
export class DatatableModule{
}
```

Comment: This actually solved the issue for my scenario. But, if the DatatableComponent is used throughout the app and if it's declared in the app.module.ts, Why this error occurs? Why It should be declared in the particular module?

Comment: @ninja I have updated my answer. You create your `DatatableModule`. And then you import it where you are going to use `DataTables`. If, for example, you are in `UserComponent`, then in your `UserModule` you have to `import` the `DatatableModule` that we created.

Comment: @ninja No, I mean the current component. Anyway, if you just create the `DatatableModule` like I did in my example and add it in `imports` in your `AppModule` it should work. Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the import to app.module.ts, I get Unexpected directive 'DataTableComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Comment: @ninja You are importing `DatatableComponent` in your `AppModule`. You have to import `DatatableModule`. That's why. Follow the examples in my answer. First create a `DatatableModule` like I did, then import it in your `AppModule` like I did in my example. If it fails, let me know and add a code sample to your question so I can check if there are some error or any other things going wrong.

Comment: @ninja remove `DataTableComponent` from your imports in `CustomersModule `. `imports` is for modules, not components.

Comment: @ninja yes, that's why I told you to remove `DataTableComponent`, not `DataTableModule`. It's normal to get confused at the beginning between Components, Modules, Directives, Pipes, Services, etc. You'll get used to this, don't worry

Comment: I updated my question with the actual code, hope it is correct, cos I still get the error...I also tried to import the module in app.module instead, still the same, wtf...?

Comment: @ninja If `CustomersModule` is imported in `AppModule` I don't see what it should not work. Update your question with the error logs please.

Comment: I get the same error as in the question- I think I'll restart a new project and do it step by step, typical of angular 2, and the only thing I got used to so far

Comment: @ninja Check my Update 1.

Comment: ok I finaly made it work, I was missing an import in my customers.module.ts

Comment: @ninja Nice! I'm glad! I hope I was of help!